# periodically check for updates while app on foreground

Tags: android, service, handler

I have been looking here on Stackoverflow and googling for a correct approach, but could not find one. I guess I won't be the only one with this issue.

I have an app that periodically checks for updated data on the server. There is a file with a timestamp which should be checked. When it has changed, it will download the new data (xml-file).

At the moment, I start a handler, for testing I just print a toast:

```
Handler h; 
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "YEEEEEP!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        h.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

Then in the `onCreate()`:

```
h = new Handler();
h.post(r);
```

in the `onDestroy()` I remove the runnables, so the handler stops when the user presses back in this Activity to exit the app.

It works OK, it keeps showing the toast while in other activities, but when the user presses the 'home' button, the app of course keeps running! What I want is, that the check for updates is only running when the user believes the app is running.

Did anyone tackle this issue before? 
If there is a better way to do this via a service, any suggestions would be welcome. But I think there is no difference in the issue when using a service.

Comment: use TimerTask Method to do it well.

Comment: I did not use a TimerTask because someone said it was bad for Android: http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Comment: no you can use it,i have used it its working fin for me.

Comment: Ok. But still, the timertask will still be running after the user returned to 'home' screen

Comment: you will have to cancle TimerTask object on onDestroy method.

Answer (score -1):

Use Broadcast receiver to check the updates. app in foreground mode.

Try with this.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
    context.startService(service);
  }
}
```

Gothrough this to get more details about broadcast receiver.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

example. http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/android-broadcast-receiver-in-detail.html

Comment: go through this  one also. http://www.edureka.in/blog/android-tutorials-broadcast-receivers/

Comment: But the service will still be running after the app has stopped, right?

Comment: if the app has stopped service also will get stop.

Comment: still not an answer...problem is that when you press 'home', the app does not stop. And are you really sure? A service is stopped when the app is stopped? Isn't this the purpose of the service, to stay alive in the background when the user leaves the app?

Comment: if the user presses the home button our broadcast receiver or services wont get stop i am damn sure about that.And also it will get stop if user do force stop the app or clear data (Manually in the manage applications). The service and broadcast receiver will stay alive if user simply leaves(By pressing home button ) .

Comment: So...please reread my question. I know that this is the case...you are giving solutions to problems I don't have...